# How to evaluate a string variable as a glob pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Let's say I have a list of files and dirs, all in the same directory:

```
files=(file1 file2 file3 dir1 dir2)
src="path/to/src"
```

I try to build a glob pattern by joining them into a string by comma:

```
files_by_comma=$(IFS=, ; echo "${files[*]}")
```

However, when I try to copy

```
cp -R "$src/{$files_by_comma}" path/to/dest
```

I get `cp: cannot stat 'path/to/src/{file1,file2,file3,dir1,dir2}': No such file or directory`. Of course if I spell out the glob by hand it works just fine:

```
cp -R /path/to/src/{file1,file2,file3,dir1,dir2} path/to/dest
```

I tried many variations like `cp -R "$src"/{"$files_by_comma"} path/to/dest` but it seems the issue is that I'm injecting a string into a glob expression, and it can't evaluate it.

Is it possible to combine a string with a glob in this case? Thanks

Comment: Order-of-evaluation matters. Brace expansion happens *before* parameter expansion. It's already complete before variables' values are considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build a string with comma as you already have file names in an array. You just need to use:

```
files=(file1 file2 file3 dir1 dir2)
src="path/to/src"

cp -R "${files[@]/#/$src/}" path/to/dest
```

Comment: It seems like only the first file gets copied, the rest fail with `cp: cannot stat 'file2': No such file or directory`

Comment: `"$src/${files[@]}"` will only apply `$src` to the first entry in the array; to get it applied to all of them, you can use a substitution to tack it on the beginning of each entry: `"${files[@]/#/$src}"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Almost there, I just had to add a trailing `/`: `"${files[@]/#/$src/}"`. Thanks a bunch!